# React - Testing controller component with jest/enzyme

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm in bit of a dead-end as I'm not sure how I should go about testing this specific "component". So basically, I have a controller component which is a top-level component. It doesn't take in any props, and it is rendered by a route component. The controller component has several functions, which some are passed into a child component and are triggered by event handlers.

Additionally, the controller component uses an API that is attached to the global window object. The API takes in a callback function which then will be called when you call certain methods on the API, after the methods have been run. Right now, I have no idea how I should try to test the controller. I have tested all child components and verified that everything works, but some of these functions within the controller component would be crucial to test that they actually do work.

```
const MyController = () => {
const [api, setApi] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
const globalApi = window.globalApi
setApi(globalApi)
init()
}, [])

function callBack(e) {
    console.log(e)
}

function init() {
        api.init(callBack)
}

function close() {
    api.close()
}

return (
    <MyComponent 
    close={close}
    />
)
```

}

Comment: why are you putting the api in the state, seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Mock your api and see if its called

You can spy on your api call from global (if I read your code correctly). Then you can mock implement it.

```
const apiCall = jest.spyOn(global.globalApi, 'init').mockImplementation(jest.fn);
expect(apiCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

There's a couple of tests you can do. Check how many times its called, should be once for you. and check what arguments it was called with.

#### Note

The use of `global` in the spy. `global` refers to the window.

### Extra tests

Beyond these tests I would suggest making a snap shot of a shallow render, just to make sure the render is always working.

Comment: I did get this to work with your comment, thank you so much. The only thing that I have trouble still with is checking if a class has been instantiated. The API returns an object, which has both functions and classes defined for different properties. It works for the "init" function, but it won't work on spying if a class has been instantiated.

Comment: mock the return value of the api as well, don't test 3rd party requests in your tests. Instead setup a pass and fail mock.